# how to count bandwidth for external ip who exhausting my vps

Tags: linux-networking

i have some troubles with determining how or who exhausting my clients vps bandwidth

i left iftop open and listen on all interfaces for port 3306 and total bandwidth is like 10g/day to mysql remote port

my question is: how i can determine bandwidth for specific external ip who connects to my mysql server

for example i have 10 remote clients connecting to mysql and i wanna know how many mb/gb generate each of them

//PS: sorry for weak english skill

//PS2: that is openvz container interfaces are venet0-localhost and venet0:1-ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use ntop on our download servers to inspect the traffic from time to time.

Ntop increases the CPU load by a good amount depending on the traffic you have (our download servers have a monthly throughput of 8 TB or more). However, you will get a nice webinterface with a lot of statistics starting from aggregated overall stats to IP:port based aggregations.

You could use the "top hosts" and then inspect them to see which ports were used or you inspect the clients of the "top ports".

Screenshots and more info about ntop: http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/

Comment: yeah that looks good but i still looking for some console like app who count total bandwidth for specified ip

Comment: I'm more the fan of graphical statistics but maybe one of these tools is better for you then (ntop has a console mode too but I think it's the old way of using it): http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20121002171429745/NetworkTools.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use [tcptrack](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/tcptrack/) to view total bandwidth used by a specific external ip on port 3306.

```
tcptrack -i any host <external-ip> and port 3306
```

You can also modify the command to list all the ip and see who is consuming the most, pressing 's' will sort by utilization.

```
tcptrack -i any port 3306
```